# How to give read and wite access to root group and others on automount for vfat filesystem?

Tags: mount, permissions, xubuntu, fstab, automount

I have a vFAT external HDD. I want to automount it on startup. I've edited the fstab as following:

```
UUID=70F7-0C26 /media/eHDDs/Transcend vfat defaults 0 0
```

But the read and write permission is allocated to only root user.

I want to read and write access to root group and others as well.

I've tried changing permission of the parent directory where it is mounted using the following command:

```
sudo chmod 0777 eHDDs/
```

Still, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after researching more, I've found out that the following edit needs to be made in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=70F7-0C26 /media/eHDDs/Transcend vfat nofail,auto,user,umask=0000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

`umask` to give read and write access to all users and `iocharset` to allow proper encoding-decoding of characters.

Comment: Side notes: Specific examples are found in [fstab on Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). Also, [this article on Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) has noted "`iocharset=utf8` allows access to files with names in non-English languages. [However], this doesn't work for Windows machines that export their shares using ISO8895-15." Anyway, good self-answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change permissions for the mount-point, not for it's parent directory, so in your case

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/eHDDs/Transcend
```

will grant read-, write- and execute-permissions for everyone.

Also it would be a good idea to add the `nofail`-option to your fstab-line. This will avoid problems if your external HDD is not connected during boot (see `man fstab`).

Comment: This does not work for vfat filesystem.

Comment: @Quoros You are right, I found out that mounting a fat-partition with default options in fstab changes the ownership of the mount-point back to `root`. Your answer helped me increasing my knowledge, upvoted.